# Why does the "What's new" section in the Google Play Store now indicate "No information from the developer"?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, google-account, google

In the Google Play Store, the *"What's new"* section for every Android app with an available update now claims "No information from the developer".

This is happening even [when developers spend their time writing text for the *"What's new"* section for the apps they publish.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264679/android-release-notes-not-showing-on-pending-downloads-page-in-google-play-stor/71306439)

I've tried clearing cache and data for both the Google Play Store and Google Play Services.  I've also tried restarting the Android device.  None of this fixed this issue.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be (another) Google bug.

The Google Play Store system seems to be broken in yet another way (it also thinks updates are available for apps when there is no compatible update available).

Release notes for *all apps* seem to be broken in the Google Play Store.

A [discussion on XDA Developers Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/google-play-no-information-from-the-developer.4408515/) indicates others having problems with Google's Play Store.

Similarly, a [discussion on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/sythga/no_information_from_the_developer_for_all_app/) talks about people having the problem with Google Play Store that you identified.  A member of that discussion postulates a hypothesis as to why this may be happening:

> Google strongly encourages turning on automatic updates and just blindly accepting every update. Sure seems like they've decided that if they blind us to what the updates contain, we'll just turn on automatic updates since we can't make informed decisions about them without the update info.

From the data I have gathered, this Google bug seems to be affecting all versions of Android.